# What is wrong with the syntax in this stored procedure?

Tags: mysql

```
DELIMITER;;
CREATE PROCEDURE ROWPERROW()
BEGIN
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE j INT DEFAULT 0;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jos_downloads_files INTO n;
SET j=0;
SET i=0;
WHILE i<n DO 
INSERT INTO jos_downloads_files_temp(id,filetitle,filetype)

SELECT DISTINCT T.id, T.filetitle, T.filetype
FROM jos_downloads_files T
LEFT JOIN jos_downloads_files T2 ON T.filetitle != T2.filetitle
WHERE T.filetitle LIKE CONCAT('%', T2.filetitle, '%') AND T.filetype like 'pdf'
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT T2.id, T2.filetitle, T2.filetype
FROM jos_downloads_files T
LEFT JOIN jos_downloads_files T2 ON T.filetitle != T2.filetitle
WHERE T.filetitle LIKE CONCAT('%', T2.filetitle, '%') AND T.filetype like 'pdf'
ORDER BY filetitle, filetype
LIMIT j,2;

set @myVar := (select filetitle from jos_downloads_files_temp where filetype like 'pdf');

set @dwg := (select id from jos_downloads_files_temp where filetype like 'dwg');

update jos_downloads_files set filetitle = @myVar where filetype like 'dwg' AND id=@dwg AND filetitle!=@myVar;

TRUNCATE TABLE jos_downloads_files_temp;

SET i = i + 1;
SET j = j + 2;

END WHILE;
END;
;;
```

results in this:

Error

SQL query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ROWPERROW()
BEGIN
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 3

Comment: That error usually means that parentheses don't match up.

Comment: Also, can ;; really work as a delimiter? I can't see how !?!

Comment: Also, unless you're using a case sensitive collation (highly unlikely) `filetype like 'pdf'` is just a slower way of saying `filetype = 'pdf'`